# Why doesn't GetElementbyId / GetElementbyTagName in VBA work correctly?

Tags: vba, web-scraping, html-table, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

my VBA code runs in mood swings

I created a VBA module to get data from 30 html pages and combine them all into a single table in my worksheet. My approach was to loop through each html page one by one, getting the data and append my worksheet after each loop.

After various adjustments, my code worked quite well, except for one problem that I have spent days but cannot figure out. The thing is the data table that I get is not exactly the same as the table displayed in the website. Sometimes it is correct, sometimes it is not. How come my code or VBA is inherent with “mood swings”, Could someone point out the error for me?
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Cao Doremi

The 1st webpage:
https://www.cophieu68.vn/atbottom.php?currentPage=1&&d=24&type=lo

source table

```
No. Symbol  Lowest
On  Current Price       +/- Volume  Highest
On  Book Price  EPS P/E
        (24_Month)
                    (24_Month)
            
1   CVRE2013
0.1 28/07/2021  0.1 
0   0   12.1    25/01/2021  0   0   0
2   CTCH2102
0.2 28/07/2021  0.2 
0   2,100   4.7 14/05/2021  0   0   0
3   CTCH2003
0.2 27/07/2021  0.2 
0   26,100  3.9 22/01/2021  0   0   0
4   CVHM2105
1.2 28/07/2021  1.1 
-0.1    50,400  6.4 17/05/2021  0   0   0
5   YEG
15.1    28/07/2021  15.1    
0.1 74,200  86.9    10/7/2019   0   -4.1    -3.7
6   CVNM2104
1.2 28/07/2021  0.9 
0   46,000  4   25/05/2021  0   0   0
7   CVHM2106
1.1 28/07/2021  1.1 
0   45,800  5.8 17/05/2021  0   0   0
```

Destination table

```
No. Symbol  Lowest

(24_Month)  On  Current Price       +/- Volume  Highest

(24_Month)  On  Book Price  EPS P/E
1   CVRE2013    0.1 28/07/2021  0.1     0   0   12.1    25/01/2021  0   0   0
2   CVRE2104    0.2 28/07/2021  0.1     0   44,700  5   14/05/2021  0   0   0
3   CTCH2102    0.2 28/07/2021  0.2     0   135,300 4.7 14/05/2021  0   0   0
4   CTCH2103    0.1 28/07/2021  0.1     0   319,000 3   14/05/2021  0   0   0
5   CVHM2105    1.2 28/07/2021  1.2     0   160,700 6.4 17/05/2021  0   0   0
6   CVHM2106    1.1 28/07/2021  1       0   234,500 5.8 17/05/2021  0   0   0
7   CVNM2104    1.2 28/07/2021  0.9     0   194,000 4   25/05/2021  0   0   0
```

code:

```vb
      Sub Gettab()
 
      Dim html As HTMLDocument
      Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
      Dim sh As Worksheet
      Dim td As Object, tr As Object, r As Long, c As Long, i As Integer
            
   
      Sheets.Add.Name = "webtab"  ' => Need to delete the "webtab" worksheet before running the code for the second time
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("webtab")
        
      r = 1
    
    For i = 1 To 30
    
        URL = "http://www.cophieu68.vn/atbottom.php?currentPage=" & str(i) & "&&d=24&type=lo&lang=en"
        
      
        Set html = New HTMLDocument

        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        End With

            
        Set table = html.getElementById("fred")
    
         
         
            For Each tr In table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ' Loop through rows topdown
            c = 1
            
            For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")  ' Loop through columns in a row (cell by cell, right to left)
                sh.Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next
            
            r = r + 1
        Next
              
                
        Set table = Nothing
        Set html = Nothing
        Set tr = Nothing
        Set td = Nothing
        
    Next
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Sometimes it is correct and sometimes not over time or during every loop? When it is incorrect does it serve values from an earlier period in time or seemingly random data? How can we reproduce this with the minimum amount of effort?

Comment: Both overtime and during every loop, QHarr.  As you can see above, Row 5 displayed in the screen is the stock YEG while Row 5 in my result worksheet is the stock CVHM2105. One theory could be that the developer of this web is running some kind of protection measures preventing data downloading by giving misleading information. How could that be? I don't quite go for this explanation, coz when I inspect the webpage, the information in the html file is exactly the same as what is displayed. The only thing is my code does not catch truly a snapshot, something must be wrong with my code,but where?